# True/ False: If $f '(c) < 0$, then $f$ is concave down at $x = c$?

Tags: calculus

Determine whether the following statement is true or false. Whether true or false, explain why. If false, also correct the statement.

> If $f'(c) < 0$, then $f$ is concave down at $x = c$.

I know the question is False because if $f'(c) < 0$, then the graph is always decreasing.

How can I correct the question to be true?

Comment: Convexity/concavity is related to the second derivative. So use $f''(c) < 0$.

Comment: "If $f'$ is decreasing on the non-degenerate interval $(a,b)$, then the graph of $f$ is concave down on $(a,b)$"; or, "if $f''<0$ on the  non-degenerate interval $(a,b)$, then the graph of $f$ is concave down on $(a,b)$". Knowing the sign at *a single point* tells you nothing. A suitable modification of example 5 [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&pg=PA37&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) will provide a function with $f''(0)<0$, but which is not concave down on any interval containing $0$.

Comment: I am not comfortable with the use of the phrase concave down **at** $x=c$. It is better to think of concavity as a property a function may have in an *interval*.

Answer (score 1):

$f'(c)$ is the slope of the function at a given point
$f"(c)$ is the concavity.

Therefore, following statements are true:

If $f'(c)<0$, then $f$ has a negative slope on point $x=c$.

If $f"(c)<0$, then $f$ is concave downward on point $x=c$.